# How do I fill a datagrid in my View with my datatable in my ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on an MVVM WPF Application managing Users. I want to display all users from the Users Table in a datagrid in my UsersView.
Here is my dataGrid

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="UsersDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding UTI_PRENOM}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last name" Binding="{Binding UTI_NOM}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Login" Binding="{Binding UTI_LOGIN}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is how I currently fill the data grid in my UsersView.cs:

```
public UsersView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getAllUsersInDataGrid();
        
    }

    private void getAllUsersInDataGrid()
    {
        using (GestUserDbContext context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var users =
                from UTILISATEUR in context.UTILISATEUR
                select new { UTILISATEUR.UTI_PRENOM, UTILISATEUR.UTI_NOM, UTILISATEUR.UTI_LOGIN };
            UsersListDataGrid.ItemsSource = users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And I would like to dispose of the View from having this responsibility (respecting MVVM) by giving it to my UsersViewModel which is currently empty.
How should I do that, I've tried to create a UsersList variable in the ViewModel and bind it thanks to itemsSource but it didn't work. Btw my view is in a ContentControl Content Binded to My ViewModel and it works for the other uses so, I don't think it's the issue.

Hope I made myself clear enough,
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I wanna add that my main problem here is that I can't use UsersListDataGrid.ItemsSource = users.ToList(); In my ViewModel since there is no UsersListDataGrid here. I'm trying to pass data through binding (UsersList) in ViewModel. I hope this is not more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to bind properly, the need to use properties etc.. which resolved my problem, I'll close the post so nobody could waste time answering me !

Edit : How I did it is instead of directly modifying the datasource of my Usergrid in my View, I created a property : `UserList` in my ViewModel which I binded to my DataGrid `ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}"`. I also made UserList setter trigger `OnPropertyChanged()` so now it updates dynamically.
Really, the main problem I had was using variables instead of properties for the databinding.

Example:

this is a variable :

```
private List<User> UserList;
```

and this is a property :

```
        private List<User> _UsersList;
        public List<User> UsersList
        {
            get
            {
                return _UsersList;
            }
            set
            {
                _UsersList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide in your answer how did you do the binding? In this way, it can help someone else that might have being dealing with the same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your binding, you can always check with mock objects, in case you are not using a unit test:

Say this is your entity class:

```
public class User
{
    public string? UTI_NOM { get; set; }
    public string? UTI_PRENOM { get; set; }
    public string? UTI_LOGIN { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the code to bind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getAllUsersInDataGrid();
    }

    private void getAllUsersInDataGrid()
    {
        List<User> usersContext = new()
        {
            new User { UTI_LOGIN = "Login1", UTI_NOM = "Nom1", UTI_PRENOM = "PreNom1" },
            new User { UTI_LOGIN = "Login2", UTI_NOM = "Nom2", UTI_PRENOM = "PreNom2" },
            new User { UTI_LOGIN = "Login3", UTI_NOM = "Nom3", UTI_PRENOM = "PreNom3" },
        };

        var users =
            from UTILISATEUR in usersContext
            select new { UTILISATEUR.UTI_PRENOM, UTILISATEUR.UTI_NOM, UTILISATEUR.UTI_LOGIN };

        UsersDataGrid.ItemsSource = users.ToList();
    }
```

The data is successfully binding:

[image: Screenshot of WPF Window]

So, probably you have a problem with your DbContext and fetching the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks you for your quick answer and edit, indeed my Binding works fine while I do it on my view as you tested, but when I do it in my ViewModel where I can't use UsersDataGrid.ItemsSource = users.ToList(); I don't know how to do it. (I will edit my post detailing this)

Comment: The primary responsibility of the ViewModel is to provide data to the view, so that view can put that data on the screen.

Comment: Yes, in my case the view gets its data itself using the DBcontext, and that bothers me.